# Htaccess url rewrite, new folder, but files load in parent folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` file changes `http://example.com/animal.php?id=number` to `http://example.com/animal/number`.

If I go to `http://example.com/animal/number`, this code loads `animal.php`'s other files in `/animal` folder, but this folder doesn't exist.

I would like for it to work if I go to `/animal/number` page, the code will load `animal.php`'s other files in parent folder (`http://example.com/`).

**Example:** I'm including `header.php` in `animal.php`, and this is working, but if I go to `/animal/number` page, this is not working, because `header.php` not in the `/animal` folder.

My `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    RewriteEngine on  

    #RewriteBase /htdocs/test

    RewriteRule    ^animal/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    animal.php?id=$1    [NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How are you including `header.php`?

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to describe is a *client-side* relative URL issue. If you are using *relative* URLs in your client-side HTML then any resources (CSS, JS, images, etc) are naturally requested relative to the `/animal` "subdirectory" (as specified in the URL), not the document root (the location of the actual document). The browser only sees the URL, not the underlying filesystem path.

You would need to resolve this by either using root-relative URLs (starting with a slash) or absolute URLs (scheme + hostname) in your client-side HTML. Alternatively you can set a `base` element in the `head` section of your HTML that tells the browser what URL to use as the base URL when resolving relative links/URLs. (However, note that there are caveats with using the `base` element if you are using in-page links with just a fragment identifier, eg. of the form `href="#internal-id"` - since this is considered a *relative* URL.)

> I'm including `header.php in`animal.php`

HOWEVER... "including `header.php`" implies a server-side include (eg. `include('header.php')`), which has nothing to do with the URL structure, relative URLs (in the HTML) and hence nothing to do with URL-rewriting and your `.htaccess` file.

Unless... you are including this as some kind of JavaScript AJAX request (or even a *frame*)? (Hence my query in the comments above.) In this case, the same relative URL problem would occur as mentioned above.